# Div element positioned below its sibling, its own children positioned above it

Tags: html, css

I have a div element that is generated right after an image. This div contains an H1 and P element. The div in question has a negative top-margin to overlap the image.

My problem is that this div shows up behind the image, and its child elements above it. This is across multiple browsers and seem to be intended behaviour, I just can't wrap my head around why and how I can overcome it.

I would *really* prefer not to use absolute positioning, as this is for a quite dynamic layout.

Problem is reproduced here: http://jsfiddle.net/mVE8L/

HTML:

```
<img src="(I'm not allowed to link images)">
<div class="problematic">
<h1>Sup guys</h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
h1 {
font-size: 3rem;
}
.problematic {
margin-top: -70px;
background: #ff0000;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a z-index problem. Just add

`position: relative;` to `.problematic` you may also add `z-index:1;` but you dont need to.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Is there any good explanation or spec for which rules that actually come in play here?

Comment: Your're welcome. I'd recommend to read this: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#positioning-scheme and this http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp good luck

Answer (score 0):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mVE8L/2/)

you can use `z-index`

```
 .problematic {
    margin-top: -70px;
    background: #ff0000;
    position:relative;
    z-index:-1;
}
```